# how would i create rule for a particular subdomain in uppercase? e.g XX.test.com

Tags: subdomain, rewritecond

I am new to system admin side.

I need to create one subdomain with capital letters. 
e.g our main URL will be test.com  and one of our sub-domain will be SS
then instead of writing ss.test.com I want it to make SS.test.com

how would I achieve that?

I tried few things on rewrite rule but not able to achieve this.

Comment: The hostname is not case sensitive. You cannot distinguish between ss and SS. They are equivalent.

Comment: i mean can make it so if anybody puts ss it will redirect to SS?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: See also [Is the hostname part of HTTP(S) URLs truly case-insensitive?](http://serverfault.com/q/672984/126632)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more precise, you CAN tell Apache, for instance, to redirect to a certain format, but then (at least some) browsers get confused because it asks for the lowercase version of the domain and gets a redirect to the same domain: Apache actually asks the browser to reformat it's request. Finding an infinite loop, firefox just tells the user the server is misconfigured and doesn't load the page.

You should actually consider case sensitivity a misconfiguration because RFCs 1178 and 1035 discourage that a server name (here domain name) to be case sensitive, and since most systems are expected to follow these recommendations, your HTTP server SHOULD NOT send a redirect to the same domain with just a different case.

Michael gave you the right answer in the comments.

Comment: See [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2).